# RPi4 USB-C hub not working on reboot

Tags: pi-4, usb-hub, usb-c

I have a LogiLink USB-C 3-Port Hub UA0315 plugged in Raspberry Pi 4 which is powered through external power supply. The hub is working when plugged in, however on reboot it is no longer detected until I manually re-plug it. RPi is running Ubuntu 18.04.

What I've tried so far:

- adding  `dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host` in */boot/firmware/usrcfg.txt* and */boot/config.txt*
- loading modules *dwc2* and *ftdi_sio* with `modprobe`
- tried with newest Raspberry Pi OS, same problem

Additional info:

For testing purposes i have connected mouse to USB 3.0 hub slot, two USB 2.0 slots are connected to ODrive board.

- [dmesg on boot](https://pastebin.com/F1e73ZhB)
- [dmesg after re-plugging USB-C hub](https://pastebin.com/hqEeQJFe)
- [udevadm monitor on re-plug](https://pastebin.com/ZkGnYArJ)
- [lsusb -v on boot](https://pastebin.com/SFXfXVw1)
- [lsusb -v after re-plugging](https://pastebin.com/eQzxK6kh)

Comment: Instead of physically replugging it, does `udevadm trigger` work? (use `-v` and `-n` for verbose and dry-run, if need be)

Comment: Hi @FelixJN , running `udevadm trigger` yields no results. 
[Output of udevadm trigger -v](https://pastebin.com/Y33epYDc)